# Reliable replacement for FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#

I'm trying to poll for newly created files.

Because the `FileSystemWatcher` class is known not to be reliable ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/240008/588868), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7191512/588868) and [here](https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/460919-filesystemwatcher-unreliable)), and because it does not wait for the end of a complete file write, I created a new class to get files creation.

The specifications are:

- Files should be signaled only when the file write is complete (large files should be signaled at the end of the copy)
- Files should be signaled only once
- Existing files (when the program starts) should be signaled
- The poller will live in a windows service. Thus it should support very long lifetime (several weeks)

Here's what I have right now:

```
public class FileSystemPoller
{
    private readonly string _path;
    private readonly CancellationToken _cancellationToken;
    private readonly string _searchPattern;
    private readonly SearchOption _searchOptions;
    private readonly HashSet<string> _filesProcessed = new HashSet<string>();
    private readonly TimeSpan _interval;

    public FileSystemPoller(
        string path,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        string searchPattern = null,
        SearchOption options = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly,
        TimeSpan? interval = null
        )
    {
        _path = path;
        _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
        _searchPattern = searchPattern ?? "*";
        _searchOptions = options;
        _interval = interval.GetValueOrDefault(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }

    private async Task PollForChanges(BlockingCollection<FileInfo> outQueue)
    {
        var di = new DirectoryInfo(_path);

        var files = di.GetFiles(_searchPattern, _searchOptions);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (!_filesProcessed.Contains(file.FullName) && !IsFileLocked(file))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"File created disk : {file.FullName}");
                outQueue.Add(file);
                _filesProcessed.Add(file.FullName);
            }
        }
        foreach (var filePath in _filesProcessed)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                _filesProcessed.Remove(filePath);
                Debug.WriteLine($"Removed from disk : {filePath}");
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("Poll directory changes");

        await Task.Delay(_interval).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await PollForChanges(outQueue).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetCreatedFiles()
    {
        if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) yield break;

        using (var queue = new BlockingCollection<FileInfo>())
        {
            PollForChanges(queue);

            if (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                foreach (var fileInfo in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(_cancellationToken))
                {
                    yield return fileInfo;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;

        try
        {
            stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open,
                     FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            //the file is unavailable because it is:
            //still being written to
            //or being processed by another thread
            //or does not exist (has already been processed)
            Debug.WriteLine($"File present but locked : {file.FullName}");

            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            stream?.Close();
        }

        //file is not locked
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code seems to work, *but*:

- if any exception occurs in the `PollForChanges`, the whole process stops
- I'm not sure if the regular scheduling of the method `PollForChanges`. Especially, I fear I eventually get trapped in a `StackOverflowException` (because the method is calling itself).
- dealing with present files, signaled files, ... is a mess in this code.
- Some refactors are suggested. Especially, calling an async method without waiting for it (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629951/suppressing-warning-cs4014-because-this-call-is-not-awaited-execution-of-the)

Globally, what are possible improvements?

Comment: Please do not add, remove, or edit code in a question after you've received an answer. The site policy is explained in [What to do when someone answers](/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Is FileSystemWatcher “not known to be reliable” or “known not to be reliable”? Is that a “commonly known” fact or can you provide some sources?

Comment: @MartinR, sorry, I'm not native english speaker, the difference is very subtile for me. Anyway, I've added some links to point to user complaining the FSW is not reliable, especiaaly when using network file shares

Comment: FileSystemWatcher is "known to be unreliable". In simple words, it doesn't work well. If the data size of the collected watcher events exceeds the size of the buffer created by FileSystemWatcher, the events that overflow are lost, and reliable exceptions are not raised. There is plentiful discussion of these issues if one googles for them. Here is but one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something wrong in the way you are using the cancellation token:

In the code `GetConsumingEnumerable()` throws if the cancellation token is set:

> ```
>         foreach (var fileInfo in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(_cancellationToken))
>         {
>           yield return fileInfo;
>         }
> ```

If you don't handle that exception the application crashes here. You can't handle the exception here with a surrounding `try-catch` because `yield` doesn't allow that.

If the caller handles it, the application doesn't crash, but the recursive `PollForChanges()` continues calling itself <=> the application continues to run/doesn't stop properly?

Therefore you should check the cancellation token in `PollForChanges()` too:

```
  private async Task PollForChanges(BlockingCollection<FileInfo> outQueue)
  {
    if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) return;
    ....
```

---

This `DirectoryInfo`:

> ```
> var di = new DirectoryInfo(_path);
> ```

should be a class member instead of a local variable, because it doesn't change per instance. It can then replace `_path`.

---

`IsFileLocked()` can be simplified with a `using` statement:

```
      using (FileStream stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
      {

      }
```

instead of the `finally` statement.

---

This `foreach`-statement will crash if a `filePath` is actually removed by it:

> ```
>   foreach (var filePath in _filesProcessed)
>   {
>     if (!File.Exists(filePath))
>     {
>       _filesProcessed.Remove(filePath);
>       Debug.WriteLine($"Removed from disk : {filePath}");
>     }
>   }
> ```

---

I don't like the recursive approach for a long running service because it builds up the stack. I would find an iterative solution instead. Beside that I don't think I understand the `async-await` approach.

I would go with a simpler approach like something below:

```
public class FileSystemPoller
{
  private readonly CancellationToken _cancellationToken;
  private readonly string _searchPattern;
  private readonly SearchOption _searchOptions;
  private readonly HashSet<string> _filesProcessed = new HashSet<string>();
  private readonly TimeSpan _interval;
  private readonly DirectoryInfo _di;

  public FileSystemPoller(
      string path,
      CancellationToken cancellationToken,
      string searchPattern = null,
      SearchOption options = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly,
      TimeSpan? interval = null
      )
  {
    _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
    _searchPattern = searchPattern ?? "*";
    _searchOptions = options;
    _interval = interval.GetValueOrDefault(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    _di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
  }

  public IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetCreatedFiles()
  {
    while (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      var files = _di.GetFiles(_searchPattern, _searchOptions);

      foreach (var file in files)
      {
        if (!_filesProcessed.Contains(file.FullName) && !IsFileLocked(file))
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"File created disk : {file.FullName}");
          _filesProcessed.Add(file.FullName);
          yield return file;
        }
      }

      _filesProcessed.RemoveWhere((p) => {
        if (!File.Exists(p))
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"Removed from disk : {p}");
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      });

      Console.WriteLine("Poll directory changes");
      Thread.Sleep(_interval);
    }
  }

  private static bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
  {
    try
    {
      using (FileStream stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
      {

      }
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
      //the file is unavailable because it is:
      //still being written to
      //or being processed by another thread
      //or does not exist (has already been processed)
      Console.WriteLine($"File present but locked : {file.FullName}");

      return true;
    }

    //file is not locked
    return false;
  }

}
```

With a test client like:

```
using (CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
{

  CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((obj) =>
  {
    try
    {

      FileSystemPoller poller = new FileSystemPoller(@"<Path>", token);

      foreach (var fi in poller.GetCreatedFiles())
      {
        // TODO: Handle each file info...
        Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
  });

  Console.ReadLine();

  tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

---

---

Another thing: have you considered to use the `FileInfo.CreationTime/LastWriteTime` etc. to track changes instead of holding `FileInfos` in memory?

Comment: Very detailled answer. Thank you very much. Some remarks: you were right, removing items from the collection within its enumeration work crash. Thanks to RemoveWhere, it is easy to solve Regarding the scheduling, I choose to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/23814733/588868, which does not stack. Finally, I removed the use of the FileInfo class, in profit a simple string that holds the file path. This is simpler and avoid loading a load of data. The consumer of the class will be responsible to process the file.

Comment: Including part of your changes : https://gist.github.com/stevebeauge/088603022062a683929abb6784451e4d

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` - this is not good at all. Why not use a timer?

Comment: Is there a reason why the `Debug.WriteLine`s turned into `Console.WriteLine`s, or is that just oversight?

Comment: @VisualMelon: I just did some tests in a Console app :-)

Comment: @t3chb0t: I'm not sure why you mean `Thread .Sleep` isn't good in this context. The method is running in a separate thread. A timer could be another solution, and you're right about the Observer pattern in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Bug

Your code is broken in `GetCreatedFiles` because you don't `await` the result of `PollForChanges`. But I guess this is intended as you cannot use `await` in an iterator. I still consider it a bug because it can happen that you start enumerating the `queue` before soemthing was added to it. In case of an exception there might be a delay so you won't get any results from it.

#### Code

I don't agree with you calling it a *poller* because it's not what it does. It's an enumerator with a delay; we can see that here:

> ```
> public IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetCreatedFiles()
> ```

The actual *poller* is the user of this class. In order to make it a *poller* you'd have to make it run without being triggered by the user.

You have two options to achieve this:

- make this class an `IObservable<FileInfo>`; see [Observer Design Pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/observer-design-pattern) or
- raise an event that the user listens to; see [Events (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/)